# Python: Generate two random integers that differ by at least k

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I generate two random integers in `range(n, m)` where `n` and `m` differ by at least `k` (i.e. `abs(n-m) >= k`)? I can think of two solutions (they are below), but the first one might become impractical with large `k`'s, and the second one is biased towards samples with `n` or `m` equal to `lower` or `upper-1`.

```
import random

def random_different_sample(lower, upper, min_diff):
    while True:
        attempt = random.sample(range(lower, upper), 2)
        if abs(attempt[0]-attempt[1]) >= min_diff:
            return attempt

def random_different_sample_1(lower, upper, min_diff):
    attempt = random.sample(range(lower, upper), 2)
    if abs(attempt[0]-attempt[1]) >= min_diff:
        return attempt
    if attempt[0] > attempt[1]:
        attempt[0] += min_diff - (attempt[0] - attempt[1])
        while attempt[0] >= upper:
            attempt[0] -= 1
            attempt[1] -= 1
    else:
        attempt[1] += min_diff - (attempt[1] - attempt[0])
        while attempt[1] >= upper:
            attempt[0] -= 1
            attempt[1] -= 1
    return attempt
```

Comment: Right now, your first method is the only correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a little math to make the solution simpler. If we require random numbers `a, b` to be chosen from `range(m, n)` such that `abs(b-a) >= k` then we know that `a` must be in `range(m, n-k)` and `b` must be in `range(m+k,n)`.

Thus, we can start by choosing `a` first, then selecting b from the the subset of available options that match your criteria:

```
a = random.randint(m, n-k)
b = random.randint(a+k, n)
```

**Note the above answer does not equally sample across all possible a,b combinations**

Here is an improved solution that will give equal weight to all combinations:

```
while(True):
    a = random.randint(m,n-k)
    b = random.randint(m+k,n)
    if abs(b-a) >= k:
        break
```

Comment: Indeed you are correct, I was thinking about the problem differently. Let me update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: It's possible to get a suitable pair with one single random integer. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45383499/6419007).

Comment: BTW, you need `randrange`, not `randint`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def randiff_sample(lower, upper, min_diff):
    if upper - lower < min_diff:
        raise ValueError("upper - lower should be larger than the minimum required difference")

    a = random.randint(lower, upper-min_diff -1)
    b = random.randint(a+min_diff, upper)
    return a,b
```

Comment: This is the same algorithm as the accepted answer. I don't think it provides a correct distribution.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get a suitable pair by picking one single random integer and applying some arithmetic.

With `lower = 0`, `upper = 10` and `min_diff = 5`, the possible pairs are:

```
[(0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 9)]
```

They form a triangle shape:

[image]

It means it's easy to calculate the [number of possible pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). It's also possible to assign a number to each of those pairs with the ["Cantor pairing function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function).

This function can be reversed: from a random integer `z`, it's possible to get an `(x,y)` pair.

Putting this all together, the code becomes:

```
from math import floor, sqrt
from random import randrange

def reverse_cantor(z):
    w = int(floor((sqrt(8 * z + 1) - 1) / 2)) # see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Inverting_the_Cantor_pairing_function
    t = (w**2 + w) // 2
    y = z - t
    x = w - y
    return (x, y)

def pick_random(lower, upper, min_diff):
    height = upper - lower - min_diff
    count = height * (height + 1) // 2
    z = randrange(0, count)
    x, y = reverse_cantor(z)
    a = lower + x
    b = upper - 1 - y
    return (a, b)
```

Let's check if the distribution is correct by creating 150000 random pairs:

```
from collections import Counter

dist = Counter(pick_random(0, 10, 5) for _ in range(150000))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels, values = zip(*sorted(dist.items()))

indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 1

plt.bar(indexes, values, width)
plt.xticks(indexes, labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Every pair is pretty close to appearing 10000 times.

Here's a distribution calculated with the first method of the accepted solution:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_random(lower, upper, k):
    num1 = random.randint(lower, upper)
    try:
        if upper - num1 < k:
            num2 = random.randint(lower, num1 - k)
        else:
            num2 = random.choice([random.randint(num1 + k, upper), random.randint(lower, num1 - k)])
    except ValueError:
        return get_random(lower, upper, k)
    return num1, num2
```

Here's my solution.

Comment: It doesn't work, `num1 - k` could be lower than `lower`.

Comment: @EricDuminil I was so confident in it, too. I've modified it so that it works now. It *could* potentially reach maximum recursion, but I think it's pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

In this case a better solution depend on the magnitude of the difference you are looking for. It can be easily achieved if we the range is wide and difference you are expecting is small. In below solution I have separated the range difference by the required limit.

```
import random 
def randomGen(upper, lower, min_diff):
    if (upper - lower) <= min_diff:
        raise ValueError ('Not possible to calculate')
    else:
        print ((upper - lower) // min_diff)
        if (upper - lower) // min_diff >= 1:
            x = random.randint(lower, int((-(min_diff/2) + (lower + upper)/2)))
            y = random.randint(int(((lower + upper)/2) + min_diff/2), upper )
            print (x,y)

min_diff = 200   
upper = 480
lower = 279

randomGen(upper, lower, min_diff)
```

Comment: You're missing some tuples. With randomGen(10,0,5), you never output `(3,8)`, `(3,9)` or `(4,9)`.

Comment: I wrote just to ensure that it produces a number at a valid pair in each iteration. Anyway I will take care of it. Thanks for highlighting this out