# Generate real pair number with certain K difference

Tags: python, c

I need to generate a pair of real numbers, randomly between a and b, with a certain real number difference k. In other, words, I need something similar (but for real numbers) to the cantor version of the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358036/python-generate-two-random-integers-that-differ-by-at-least-k/45383499#45383499).

[Python: Generate two random integers that differ by at least k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358036/python-generate-two-random-integers-that-differ-by-at-least-k/45383499#45383499)

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problems did you run into? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By the way, some of the solutions provided to the question you linked yourself apply to real numbers just as well as integers - did you have problems implementing any of them?

Comment: This answer on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2437916/is-the-cantor-pairing-function-guaranteed-to-generate-a-unique-real-number-for-a) says that the Cantor pairing function can't be generalized to real numbers. Are you looking for a solution based on creating a function from `R` to `R^2`, or are you only looking to avoid a rejection-sampling strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Pick the first number from [a, b-k] and add k to get the second number:

```
import random

a, b = 0, 10
k = 3.141

x = random.uniform(a, b - k)
y = x + k

print(x, y)
```